# css translate div to their parent

Tags: css, css-transitions, translate

I have a back-end background and I'm actually learning the front

my problem is with **css transition**

I'm trying to make a translation on all elements inside a div to join the top of this specific div

the best I could accomplish is moving them with a specific value or move them on X-axe wich don't interest me

you can see an example of the expected behavior in this fiddle( sorry for the code it's a learning state so lots of words)

https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/3878/

```
<div>
<p1>
<p2>
<p3>
<p4>
</div>
```

I understand the fact if I can move them on X-axe its because they can move inside their element but ...

I simply want them to all join the position of p1 (the highter p) when I click, it must be simple but as it's all new to me they must have something I missed

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way here is to adjust the `height` to 0 and keep overflow to have the needed effect. But since we cannot animate `height` from auto to 0 we can use `max-height` instead (also don't forget the default margin of `p`).

Here is a simplified example where I use hover:

```css
.anime {
  display:inline-block;
  min-height:100px;/*to avoid flickering*/
}

.anime p {
 transition:1s all;
 max-height:50px;
}

.anime:hover p {
  max-height:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="anime">
<p>Photo 1</p>
<p>Photo 2</p>
<p>Photo 3</p>
<p>Photo 4</p>
</div>
```